# Elemental Novel where boy discovers he can talk to the 4 different elements

Tags: story-identification

This was a book that was free on Amazon Kindle just a few years back. Lost my account and, subsequently, access to this book.

The book is about a kid named Tan who slowly learns that he can talk to or use the different elements. (Earth, Water, Fire, Air, and eventually Spirit)

There's a woman that Tan has to save who has the ability to use/talk to spirit.

The enemies were these beings consumed by fire. At some point, Tan struggles with being consumed by fire.

The climax of the story has the character Tan climbing in a pool that was protected by all four elements. That's where he first hears the element of spirit I think.

There are also dragons who were the first to use the elements. That is how Tan communicates with them, through the element of fire.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [*Chased by Fire*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/23363200) by D.K. Holmberg.

Hero named Tan, dragons, elemental magic, etc.

> An ancient artifact that must be found... Terrifying creatures from
> dark and dangerous Incendin... And long-forgotten elementals again
> unleashed on the world. As an earth senser, Tan is tasked with helping
> guide the king's servant through the dangerous mountain passes in
> search for the artifact before Incendin can reach it first. But after
> losing his father to the war, Tan wants nothing to do with the king's
> demands. When everything he knows is lost, he is forced to risk
> himself to save the one person who can find the artifact, a beautiful
> girl who has lost as much as Tan. In doing so, power the world hasn't
> seen in nearly a thousand years is awoken, and a warrior long thought
> dead returns to claim the artifact for himself.

Comment: Thanks! Spent way too long thinking about this.

Answer (score 6):

If by "dragon" you mean "draasin," then you're probably thinking of [*Chased by Fire*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1859250) (2014) by D. K. Holmberg, the first book of [*The Cloud Warrior Saga*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/153898-the-cloud-warrior-saga).  The draasin (fire elemental) pictured on the first book has a very definite "dragon" look to it:

[image: Cover of "Chased by Fire" showing a dragon-like beast on a rocky peak overlooking a valley with mountains in the background and a fiery setting sun.]

The hero is Tannen, called Tan, and he initially believes himself to be an "earth senser," one with an affinity for the earth.  He travels with a young woman (Amia) of another racial grouping (Aeta) who is able to shape spirit.

Initially Tan has the inexplicable power of being able to perceive other people's shapings, even Amia's whose spirit shapings are unknown to any of his people.  But over the course of his adventures he befriends various powers - elementals, basically - and he can call them to his aid, like the nymid (water elementals) who save him and help him in their first confrontation with the lisincend.  He later calls the draasin to aid them in escaping the lisincend in their final confrontation.

The lisincend are referred to by the elementals as "Twisted Fire" and are seeking to usurp the power of fire (and destroy the draasin) to gain the power to attack the Great Mother (essentially God) herself.

In the second book (*Bound by Fire*) Tan learns to speak to udilm (greater water elementals), ara (air elementals) and golud (earth elementals).